# sqlcmd error There are no batches in the input script. only if sql file contains GO

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse, sqlcmd

`sqlcmd` has strange behaviour on windows 10 yet works properly on Ubuntu linux box ... when the SQL file does NOT contain `GO` it seems OK as per

```
cat  some.sql

SELECT s.name AS schema_name,
       s.schema_id,
       u.name AS schema_owner
FROM sys.schemas s
     INNER JOIN sys.sysusers u ON u.uid = s.principal_id
ORDER BY s.name;
```

run as

```
sqlcmd -S foo-bar-dev-baz-001.sql.azuresynapse.net -d  My_Synapse_Dedicated_SQL_Pool  -I -i some.sql
```

however when my SQL file contains `GO` it seems to execute OK yet outputs error

> There are no batches in the input script.

as per

```
cat select_schema_with_GO.sql

SELECT s.name AS schema_name,
       s.schema_id,
       u.name AS schema_owner
FROM sys.schemas s
     INNER JOIN sys.sysusers u ON u.uid = s.principal_id
ORDER BY s.name;
GO
```

here is the run where sql file above contains `GO`

```
sqlcmd -S foo-bar-dev-baz-001.sql.azuresynapse.net -d  My_Synapse_Dedicated_SQL_Pool  -I -i select_schema_with_GO.sql
schema_name                                                                                                                      schema_id   schema_owner    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADMIN                                                                                                                                     14 dbo             
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_SELECTION_TOOL                                                                                                        22 dbo             
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb                                                                                                         24 dbo             
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc                                                                                                              42 dbo             

(45 rows affected)
Msg 104309, Level 16, State 1, Server foo-bar-dev-baz-001, Line 1
There are no batches in the input script.
```

I am executing this on a windows 10 box using git-bash terminal connecting to a database on Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL pool

```
sqlcmd -?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 15.0.2000.5 NT
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

So should I just ignore the (error) message

> There are no batches in the input script.

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour with sqlcmd 16.0.4025.1 NT or v0.15.4 (go-sqlcmd).

Comment: The `GO` is a SSMS reserve keyword used to run SQL in different batches. When you run it outside SSMS, try to avoid the `GO`. "GO is not a Transact-SQL statement" : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Delta correct that `GO` isn't a T-SQL statement, and it's not supported by the `sqlcmd` utility when using the `-q` or `-Q` command line parameters, but it's supposed to be supported [when used in files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility#sqlcmd-commands): _The file may include any sqlcmd command. This includes the batch terminator GO._

Comment: Scott, I wonder if there's a difference between the `-i` command line parameter and the CLI `:r` command? Have you tried reading the file using `:r`?

Comment: Perhaps you have some unprintable characters after your `GO` and that's causing a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

> "There are no batches in the input script"

The above line is not an error message, but a message indicating that there are no more batches to execute. When you use the GO command in your SQL script, it divides the script into batches, and each batch is executed separately. The above message is displayed after the last batch has finished execution.

In this case, the SQL script is run successfully, and the message is just a notification that no further batches are needed to be run. Therefore, you can ignore the message and consider SQL script's execution as successful.

Comment: I realize it works even when it shows that message ...  that message should not appear if command is successful to adhere to normal etiquette